# Composer require a fork of a fork

Tags: git, github, dependencies, composer-php, git-fork

My primary goal is to change a dependency version in the **slack** repo.
In my project, I need to use **slack-laravel** which is depended on **slack**.

What I did:

- forked both *slack* and *slack-laravel*
- changed the required dependency version in *slack* and pushed it to a branch called `guzzle-patch`
- changed the original *slack* dependency in *slack-laravel* to my forked *slack* like so:

  ```
  "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/gofilord/slack"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "maknz/slack": "dev-guzzle-patch"
  },
  ```
- I then did a `composer update` and it worked with no problems.
- finally, I pushed this update to a new `guzzle-patch` branch in my forked *slack-laravel*

**The problem:**
When I try to `composer update` **in my project**, pointing to my forked *slack-laravel*, it throws an error:

```
Problem 1
  - Installation request for maknz/slack-laravel dev-guzzle-patch -> satisfiable by maknz/slack-laravel[dev-guzzle-patch].
  - maknz/slack-laravel dev-guzzle-patch requires maknz/slack dev-guzzle-patch -> no matching package found.
```

**My composer.json:**

```
"repositories": [
  ...
  {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/gofilord/slack-laravel"
  }
],

"require": {
    ...
    "maknz/slack-laravel": "dev-guzzle-patch"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply require dependencies with dev stability, you'd have to allow them in the root package.

Also, you should rethink depending on branches. This will hurt you in the long run because you will have a very hard time rolling back to a known working state - and with more than one package being used with a branch, you add more moving parts that all somehow rely on each other. It will be a mess, you have been warned. Note that tagging versions is probably the easiest way to do ever, and it will prevent things to go south that way.

Tagging versions will solve your problem.

Alternatively, `"minimum-stability": "dev"` would allow dev, alpha, beta or RC versions of ALL packages you require (probably not a very desirable thing), so additionally `"prefer-stable":true` should also be set.